# Possibility of buffer allocation in header files

Tags: c

I'd like to know if it is possible in C to allocate memory in the header file to make it easy for me. For instance, in my source code, I allocate `data` buffer like this:

```
float *data = malloc((10*10) * sizeof(float));
```

My code is going to be compared with other person's code so I want to only insert my function `cluster(data, p, dim, ...)` in his code and just add my header (which already includes all buffers allocation) as well. Is this valid?

Thank you,

Comment: `static inline void cluster (...) { .... float *data = malloc((10*10) * sizeof(float)); ...}`....but should be avoided as evil....

Comment: What have you tried? What does the compiler say about your attempt?

Comment: Any reason you don't use a static variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can #include a header wherever you like, so this is entirely legal if not exactly great style

```
int myFunction()
{
#include "myfile.h"
}
```

However, it looks horrible to me and would be deserving of down voting to oblivion.

The problem you have is that your line

```
float *data = malloc((10*10) * sizeof(float));
```

is illegal outside the body of a function. You have two ways around this. You can wrap it in a function:

```
float* getFloatArray(int count)
{
    return malloc(count * sizeof(float));
}
```

If you only want a single instance even if you call it more than once:

```
float* getFloatArray(int count)
{
    static float* singleton = NULL;
    if (singleton == NULL)
    {
        singleton = malloc(count * sizeof(float));
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

However, if you put that in your header you run the danger of getting link time duplicate symbols. If you make it static, you'll get the same fucntion defined in each compilation unit you include the header in.

As olaf has observed, however, your arguments to malloc are constant, so you could just define a static array:

```
static float data[10 * 10];
```

However, you will still get a new instance for each compilation unit.

I would add it (the array or the function) to a new .c file and put an extern def in your header and then add your c file to the link stage.

Answer (score 1):

You never want to do that, because you would allocate memory each time you include the header, which would be a pretty severe and unexpected side-effect. The purpose of header files is to define an interface. There are some rare technical exceptions with inline functions and (in C++) with templates, which may require providing implementations directly in the header.

Answer (score -1):

No, unlike C++ it is not allowed in C to call a function in global scope at program startup.

Comment: C programs start with main or an alternative entry point. C++ programs start with functions (usually constructors) called in global scope, then call main.

Comment: Yes and in this sense "progam startup" means whatever code `main` executes. Said that, most platforms allow to call functions before `main`. The GNU toolchain and its crt typically allow functions to be attributed as ctors/dtors which are called before resp. after `main`. Similiar for some frameworks. But it is not clear that's actually what OP really wants.

Comment: @olaf Putting the line in the question in a global scope i.e. outside of the body of a function is illegal in C. The error in clang is "not a compile time constant".

Comment: @JeremyP: Where did I say it wa valid?

Comment: @olaf it's implicit in your criticism of Malcolm's answer.

Comment: You certainly implied that it was allowed to call a function in C in global scope, i.e. not in the scope of main or one of its subroutines.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: Please cite the section I stated it. Opposite, I was very clear it is not: "Said that, most platforms allow to **call functions** before ..." - A function certainly does not imply "arbitrary snippets **outside** a function body".